# How do I Select Manual Medoids in PAM Clustering in r?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pam

I am trying to specify my own medoids in a PAM algorithm, but no matter what I specify, it chooses its own.

Using dummy data below, if I put the data into cluster::pam and try to specify rows 1 and 5 (or any other options) as the medoids, it picks different rows as an output.

```
# Dummy Data
data <- data.frame(age = 1:10, height = 1:10, weight = 10:1, size = 10:1)

# Cluster
library(cluster) 
pam_fit <- pam(data, metric = "euclidean", k = 2, medoids = c(1, 5))

# Output
pam_fit$medoids
     age height weight size
[1,]   2      2      9    9
[2,]   7      7      4    4
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the input for Medoids if not row numbers? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Set argument "do.swap" to FALSE to keep the manually selected medoids.

```
pam_fit <- pam(data, metric = "euclidean", k = 2, medoids = c(1, 5), do.swap = FALSE)

# Output
pam_fit$medoids
      age height weight size
[1,]   1      1     10   10
[2,]   5      5      6    6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed

Comment: Is this also possible to do for the clara clustering algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add first the clustering output to your data

data2 <- mutate(data, cluster = pam_fit$clustering)

2) Then select the rows while applying the fit medoids:

data2[pam_fit$medoids,]